# Determine what interfaces a type implements

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface

Just a quick one... How do I determine what interfaces a type implements?

Cheers
Anthony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Type.GetInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can call the `GetInterfaces` method.

```
Type[] interfaceTypes = myType.GetInterfaces();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Type.GetInterfaces()
```

:)